# Platformer without canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, game, dom

Well I had a idea about making a platformer but wanted to challenge myself to doing it without using canvas. It uses some other codes from github for collision detection.

[Here is the result](https://jsfiddle.net/5dL266kL/2/).

```js
var currentKey; //records the current key pressed
var charSpeed = 40; //how fast the character will move
var coll = setInterval(col, 5);


function checkb(cb) {
  return cb == "b";
}

function checkr(cr) {
  return cr == "r";
}

function checkl(cl) {
  return cl == "l";
}

function checkt(ct) {
  return ct == "t";
}

function checke(ce) {
  return ce == "e";
}

function col() {
  var c = [colCheck($('#character'), $('#box1')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box2')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box3')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box4')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box5')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box6')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box7'))];

  var col = collision($('#character'), $('#trap1'));
  var col1 = collision($('#character'), $('#trap2'));
  var col2 = collision($('#character'), $('#end'));
  if (col == true || col1 == true) {
    self.location['replace'](location);
    clearInterval(coll);
  }
  if (col2 == true) {
    alert("You Won!!");
    self.location['replace'](location);
    clearInterval(coll);
  }
  if (c.some(checkr)) {
    $('#character').css("left", '-=15');
  }
  if (c.some(checkl)) {
    $('#character').css("left", '+=15');
  }
  if (c.some(checkb)) {}
  if (c.some(checkt)) {
    $('#character').css("top", '+=45');
  }
  if (!c.some(checkb)) {
    $('#character').css("top", '+=2');
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  return onkey(ev, ev.keyCode, true);
}, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
  return onkey(ev, ev.keyCode, false);
}, false);


function onkey(ev, key, down) {
  if (down && $('#character').queue("fx").length == 0) {
    if (key == 100 || key == 68 ) {
      moveChar("right");
    } else if (key == 65 || key == 97 ) {
      moveChar("left");
    } else if (key == 87 || key == 119 ) {
      moveCharu("up");
    }
  }
}

function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}

function colCheck($div1, $div2) {
  // get the vectors to check against
  var vX = ($div1.offset().left + ($div1.outerWidth(true) / 2)) - ($div2.offset().left + ($div2.outerWidth(true) / 2)),
    vY = ($div1.offset().top + ($div1.outerHeight(true) / 2)) - ($div2.offset().top + ($div2.outerHeight(true) / 2)),
    // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
    hWidths = ($div1.outerWidth(true) / 2) + ($div2.outerWidth(true) / 2),
    hHeights = ($div1.outerHeight(true) / 2) + ($div2.outerHeight(true) / 2),
    colDir = "e";

  // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
  if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
    // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
    var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
      oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
    if (oX >= oY) {
      if (vY > 0) {
        colDir = "t";
        $div1.offset().top += oY;
      } else {
        colDir = "b";
        $div1.offset().top -= oY;
      }
    } else {
      if (vX > 0) {
        colDir = "l";
        $div1.offset().left += oX;
      } else {
        colDir = "r";
        $div1.offset().left -= oX;
      }
    }
  }
  return colDir;
}

//Process Character Move Function
function moveChar(dir) {
  if (dir == "left") {
    //don't let the character move any further left if they are already at the left side of the screen  
    if ($('#character').position().left > 0) {
      $('#character').animate({
        left: '-=15'
      }, charSpeed);
    }
  }
  if (dir == "right") {
    $('#character').animate({
      left: '+=15'
    }, charSpeed);
  }
}

function moveCharu(dir, ) {
  var c = [colCheck($('#character'), $('#box1')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box2')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box3')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box4')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box5')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box6')), colCheck($('#character'), $('#box7'))];

  if (dir == "up") {
    //don't let the character move any further up if they are already at the top of the screen and also don't let char air jump.
    if (c.some(checkb)) {
      var jump = setInterval(function() {
        $('#character').css({
          top: '-=8'
        }, );
      }, 1);
      var clearjump = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(jump);
      }, 790);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#character {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 250px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 500px;
  left: 600px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 500px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box5 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 300px;
  left: 700px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box6 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 200px;
  left: 1050px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#box7 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  top: 550px;
  left: 450px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#trap1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#trap2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 250px;
  left: 1000px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#end {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1225px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id=my>
<a>use W A D to move</a>
  <div id="character"></div>
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box5" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box6" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box7" class="box"></div>
  <div id="trap1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="trap2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="end" class="box"></div>
</body>
```

(I know it's super messy and there is a lot of useless stuff but... eh?)

Any ideas for improve? Or just comments it doesn't matter

Comment: this is insane.. that red block sure can jump

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Review of DOM game

Games coding is not easy and you have managed the fundamentals of a platformer, great work.

Unfortunately your game is technically flawed in a number of areas however first I will go over some design points.

### Syntax

Your code syntax is not bad, but its also not great, specifically how you name variables and functions.

You have functions `moveChar` and `moveCharu` ?? maybe better names would be `movePlayerHorizontal`, `movePlayerUp`.

All the code is full of bad naming. You should give a little more cognitive time to naming because as code complexity grows, bad naming starts to come back and bite you.

### Refresh rate

Your update rate is way to high. Also you are creating an animation and should use the appropriate APIs.

See technical report at bottom.

### Game level design.

A level needs a lot of work to balance and get the play-ability just right. Anything that gets in the way of level changes will effect the final quality of the game.

You have hard-coded the level, in code, HTML, and CSS. This makes it very hard to make changes.

It would be better if you created an abstract data structure that held the level data, and then you build the DOM from that, setting the CSS properties as you do.

For example the following creates the play elements for your from an abstract level object that contains only the unique data related to the level elements. Though a little more complex than creating CSS and HTML, it makes it much easier to change the level design.

```js
const boxColor = "#D0D0D0";
const trapColor = "red";
const endColor = "yellow";
const characterColor = "blue";
const createElement = (top, left, width, height, color) => ({top, left, width, height, color})
function addLevel(container, level){
    var idPrefix = "";
    function addElement(item,id){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "box";
        div.id = isNaN(id) ? id : idPrefix + (id + 1);
        div.style.top = item.top + "px";
        div.style.left = item.left + "px";
        div.style.width = item.width + "px";
        div.style.height = item.height + "px";
        div.style.backgroundColor = item.color;
        container.appendChild(div);
        return div
    }
    addElement(level.character, "character");
    idPrefix = "box";
    level.boxes.forEach(addElement);
    idPrefix = "trap";
    level.traps.forEach(addElement);
    addElement(level.end, "end");
}    
    
const level1 = {
    character : createElement(0, 0, 50, 50, characterColor),
    boxes : [
        createElement(250, 0, 500, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(200, 400, 50, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(500, 600, 250, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(500, 400, 50, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(300, 700, 300, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(200, 1050, 200, 50, boxColor),
        createElement(550, 450, 50, 50, boxColor),
    ],
    traps : [
        createElement(300, 500, 100, 50, trapColor),
        createElement(250, 1000, 50, 50, trapColor),    
    ],
    end : createElement(100, 1225, 25, 25, endColor),
}

addLevel(gameContainer, level1);
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a>use W A D to move</a>
<div id="gameContainer"></div>
```

The code above creates a DOM that is almost identical to the one you created by hand. Adding a level only need another level object.

You could build the level from a text file that is a map. Or you could build it from a image where pixel colours represent level elements. Ultimately if you were creating a professional game you would most likely also create an inhouse level editor, many times the level editor also plays the game.

### JQuery

To keep it short, don't use JQuery - it is making your life harder because your code is more complex, your game requires more resources, and more...

Your function the jQuery way

> ```
> function collision($div1, $div2) {
>   var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
>   var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
>   var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
>   var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
>   var b1 = y1 + h1;
>   var r1 = x1 + w1;
>   var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
>   var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
>   var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
>   var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
>   var b2 = y2 + h2;
>   var r2 = x2 + w2;
>
>   if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
>   return true;
> }
> ```

The same function the vanilla way

```
function collision(div1, div2) {
  const a = div1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const b = div2.getBoundingClientRect();
  return ! (a.bottom < b.top || a.top > b.bottom || a.right < b.left || a.left > b.right);
}
```

not only less code for you to type but it runs many times faster.

<sub><sub>*Yes a little unfair, but we all know jquery has had its day. People need to be weened off.*</sub></sub>

---

## Technical

There is no reason you can not write a game using only DOM elements to represent the many display elements of a game, but you must work in unison with the DOM and not against it.

#### Display rate

All the top browsers present graphics to the display at the same rate, 60fps (irrespective of display rate, your monitor and PC may be running 120fps but the browser still presents at 60fps) which is once every 16.6667ms.

This mean that if you update the DOM at rates higher than the frame rate only the changes made closest to the next frame update are visible, the rest never makes it to the screen.

You have an interval timer set to 5ms, this is 3 times higher than the refresh rate. That means 2 out of every 3 updates you make to the DOM never make it to the display.

You could set the interval to 1000/60 to more closely match the display rate, but this is still not going to work. First the interval is an integer value and the display rate is not an integer rate. This means every ~second in time, you skip a frame. `setInterval` will always create animation with **jank**.

Worse still the interval timing is more or less about every so often. If you take the average over time the interval is good, if you measure the interval time per call it drifts wildly, adding even **more Jank!**

And worse even more: The interval has no idea that it is used to display content. It starts its timer from when you make the call `setinterval` which may be mid way through a display frame. At worst the changes you make will take a further 16.667ms to be displayed, or will be displayed immediately, or it may skip randomly between the two. **jank on Jank! on JANK!!**

#### All JavaScript animation should use `requestAnimationFrame`

Whenever you make changes to the DOM at a regular interval you should use `requestAnimationFrame`. It is like a `setTimeout` call but it marks the function it calls as special. It has a fixed optimal rate that is matched to the device display hardware.

For animation you typically create a `mainLoop` that creates/modifies all the visual content for each frame. It also triggers or executes directly the abstract game state, (where characters are, when to start sound FX, etc)

```
// The next line will start the loop
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
// the main loop function called 60 times a second is all goes well
function mainLoop(time){ // time is argument passed to the callback by the DOM

    // game logic
    // and visual update

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

### Functions trigger reflow

For animation, character jumping, and whatever, you need to sync it up with the main loop. You have a jump interval timer set to 1ms. 15 out of 16 calls never get displayed, but that is minor compared to what that timer function does to the browser

Each function call that changes the DOM forces a DOM re-flow and composition cycle.

Your tiny little jump function is in reality a monster processing load. Your game will drain a device's battery in a noticeable way, start fans, and make the world warmer.

The function called for jump.

```
function() {
    $('#character').css({
      top: '-=8'
    });
};
```

The two screen shots of performance (Chrome dev tools) highlighting the effect this function has on performance. Note that green represents GPU use (compositing).

[image]

- At the top is a zoom of the timeline showing the compositing caused by the function
- Center with annotations showing start and end of jump function interval
- Bottom zoom in showing just one composition event that is almost 10ms long.

You need to control all animation from a main loop.

### Why games don't use the DOM

Graphics represent a huge amount of processing, this is why almost every modern device has dedicated hardware who's sole purpose is to manipulate pixels and pixel data. This hardware is called the Graphics Processing Unit (GPU). When you make a change to the DOM via Javascript function, when that functions exits, the browser will start a series of steps to turn those changes from abstract data `{color : red, top : 10px...}` to actual pixels.

The first step is called re-flow, where the browser defines the position and size of elements in a simpler yet still abstract form. This is done by the device CPU and the time taken will depend on the complexity of the DOM.

The next step is called compositing, this converts the re-flow abstraction to pixels. This is done by the CPU controlling the GPU and is the most intensive part of the process. The DOM is a layered layout and compositing needs to create each layer's pixels, then draw the layers in the correct order to create the final display result. That result is moved (or references set) to a special section of memory to finally be turned into illuminated elements (pixels) on the display.

Browser manufacturers set their most talented people to the task of building the software for  these parts of the browsers. Browser re-flow and compositing is state of the art and getting better every day.

BUT

The browser does not read your mind, it does not understand what your code wants. It needs to handle every case for any content no mater how it is created, not matter if it follows the rules or is full of flaws and ambiguity. This is a problem for the browsers and for game creators.

Graphically the DOM is optimized for everyone, and thus sadly is not optimized for your need or anyone else.

We use the canvas because the canvas lets us skip the DOM's re-flow and compositing and control the process directly and only with our special needs in mind. This lets us skip a zillion lines of browser complexity that is not needed.

When you render to the canvas and the function exits (and if you have a well designed page) the DOM does not need to do a re-flow, if you set the alpha flag for the canvas to false, it may not even need to do a composition.

We use the canvas because the canvas side steps the cover all process of creating and animating content built into the browser. It is the best way  to create high quality complex interactive animations, such as games.

The DOM game will never compete with a canvas game no matter how good the coder is.

Comment: +1 "or will be displayed immediately, or it may skip randomly between the two. **jank on Jank! on JANK!!**" - nice! And then "_Your tiny little jump function is in reality a monster processing load. Your game will drain a device's battery in a noticeable way, start fans, and make the world warmer._" - say no to global warming!

Comment: Well I wanted the thank in the first place but i decided to wait untill now cuz i listened and learned a lot from you and made this == https://my-own-universe-in-internet.neocities.org/WalkingImage3.htm Now with your advices i learned a lot so THANK YOU VERY MUCH.What i made is still not good but again ill be working on it

Answer (score 1):

#### Const and let instead of var

Unless browser support is an issue, use [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), to limit the scopes of variables and ensure that values that shouldn't get re-assigned are consistent.x

```
let currentKey; //records the current key pressed
const charSpeed = 40; //how fast the character will move
const coll = setInterval(col, 5);
```

#### Store DOM references

Every DOM-query (e.g. `$('#character')`) is expensive. Instead, store those references in a variable and use that variable instead of re-querying the DOM.

```
const character = $('#character');
const boxes = $('.box');
const trap1 = $('#trap1');
const trap2 = $('#trap2');
const end = $('#end');
```

then in `function col()` use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access individual boxes:

```
var c = [colCheck(character, boxes.eq(0)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(1)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(2)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(3)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(4)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(5)), colCheck(character, boxes.eq(6))];
```

That array could also be created using a loop:

```
var c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    c.push(colCheck(character, boxes.eq(i)));
}
```

Or if you want to use a function approach, use [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var c = Array(7).fill('0').map(function(val, index) {
    return colCheck(character, boxes.eq(index));
});
```

#### Checking arrays for values

Perhaps you like the functional approach to check the arrays for a value (i.e. `if (c.some(checkr)) {`) but that could be simplified using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if (c.includes('r')) {
    character.css("left", '-=15');
}
```

Or if [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) is an issue, use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (c.indexOf('r') > -1) {
    character.css("left", '-=15');
}
```

#### Empty case?

The following block appears to have no expression when the condition is true. Is that left over from debugging? I see another block a few lines later with the opposite condition...

```
  if (c.some(checkb)) {}
```

For more information about Javascript code that interacts with the DOM, read [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). I know it criticizes use of jQuery at first, but the rest of the information is really valuable.